# how to get individual parameters using regular expression

Tags: regex, apache-flex

Here is a string, `func("abc", "def", "ghi")`, I want to get the individual parameter using regular expression `'"\"".*"\""'`, but it doesn't work, it will matches all of the arguments. How to get the individual parameter using regular expression?

Comment: Which application language are you using?

Comment: Flex. I want to get every function parameter using regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this one may give what you want:

```
"[^"]*"
```

above is just the regex, you may need quote it to use in your programming language.

Comment: Your regex is working properly when I quoted `"`. Thank you! According to your regex, I wrote another regex to inspect the unterminated string : `"[^"]*"$`

Answer (score 3):

`.*` is greedy i.e it would match as much as possible

You have to make `.*` match lazily using `.*?`

`.*?` is lazy i.e it would match as less as possible

So your regex would be

```
"".*?""
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still cannot get the proper result.

Comment: @Kecise you may not have escaped `"` properly